# operating system LRU page replacement in c++

Tags: c++, operating-system

I am trying to simulate least recently used (LRU) page replacement Algorithm in c++ and the function doesn't work properly.

nop = number of pages , nof = number of frames

expected output :

[image]

my code output :

[image]

so here is my code . any help would be appreciated.

note : I am still a beginner so please try to keep simplicity and thanks in advance .

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void FIFO (int nop , int nof , int *page , int *frame , int *fcount  )
{
    int i=0 , count = 0 ;
    while(i<nop)
    {
        int j=0,flag=0;
        while(j<nof)
        {
            if(page[i]==frame[j]){  //Checking whether page already exist in frames or not
            flag=1;
            fcount[j]=i+1;

            }
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
        cout<<"\n\t**************************************\n";
        cout<<"\t"<<page[i]<<"-->";
        if(flag==0) 
        {
            int min=0,k=0;
            while(k<nof-1)
            {
                if(fcount[min]>fcount[k+1]) //Calculating the page which is least recently used
                    min=k+1;
                k++;
            }
            frame[min]=page[i]; //Replacing it
            fcount[min]=i+1;    //Increasing the time
            count++;           //counting Page Fault
            while(j<nof)
            {
                cout<<"\t|"<<frame[j]<<"|";
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"\n\t**************************************\n";
    cout<<"\nPage Fault is:"<<count;

}  
int main() {
    int nop,nof,i,count=0;
    cout<<"Enter the No. of Pages:  ";
    cin>>nop; 
    int page[nop];
    cout<<"\nEnter the Reference String:  ";

    for(i=0;i<nop;i++) {
        cout<<"\t"; 
        cin>>page[i];   
    }

    cout<<"\nEnter the No of frames:  ";
    cin>>nof;
    int frame[nof],fcount[nof];
    for(i=0;i<nof;i++) {
        frame[i]=-1; //Store the frames
        fcount[i]=0; //Track when the page is last used
    }

    FIFO ( nof , nop , page , frame , fcount) ; 
    return 0 ;  
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "doesn't work properly". What are your inputs, expected results, and actual results?

Comment: I have edited the question : expected output and my code output provided

Comment: Please don't post images. Post text.